# .NET Framework (v 4.0) COM Registration free called from Win32 C++ application

Tags: c#, c++, com, registration-free-com

I need to create a registration free COM object in .Net Framework using C#.

I've followed the [MSDN walkthrough](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973915.aspx). I've to work on it because, or it is not enough clear to me, or it is not correct, however this is an old post and I use Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10, so maybe something is changed.

Here in the following the steps that I've made to make it work:

1. Compile COM C# dll `SideBySide.dll` (Target Framework 2.0), of course I've not registered it by regasm.
2. I don't use the approach described in the tutorial, it seems not work for me. I create `SideBySide.Manifest` by `mt.exe`, here's the command:

   `mt -outputresource:"<path SidebySide.dll>" -manifest "<SideBySide.manifest>"`
3. I've manually modified the generated manifest to remove all not useful tags, and add the mandatory ones. Here is the modified manifest:

   ```xml
   <assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
       <assemblyIdentity
           name="SideBySide"
           version="1.0.0.0"
           type="win32" />
       <clrClass
           clsid="{4B72FC46-C543-4101-80DB-7777848D1357}"
           progid="SideBySide.SideBySideClass"
           threadingModel="Both"
           name="SideBySide.SideBySideClass"
           runtimeVersion="v2.0.50727">
       </clrClass>
       <file name="SideBySide.dll">
       </file>
   </assembly>
   ```
4. I've added the manifest to `SideBySide.dll` with this command:

   `mt -outputresource:"<Path SidebySide.dll>" -manifest "SideBySide.manifest"`
5. I've exported the TLB from `SideBySide.dll using` tlbexp`.
6. I've set **No** in the configuration `Properties -> Manifest tool -> Embed Manifest` of the C++ client.
7. I've compiled `client.exe`, and then I've applied changes to the `client.exe.manifest` file. Here is the modified manifest:

   ```xml
   <assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
       <assemblyIdentity
           type = "win32"
           name = "client"
           version = "1.0.0.0" />
       <dependency>
           <dependentAssembly>
               <assemblyIdentity
                   type="win32"
                   name="SideBySide"
                   version="1.0.0.0" />
           </dependentAssembly>
       </dependency>
   </assembly>
   ```

Everything is working well, and it seems that I can consume the .Net Framework COM interface from the native C++ application.

However, there is an issue when I try to compile `SideBySide.dll` with .Net Framework 4.0 or newer, when I call `CreateInstance`:

```cpp
ISideBySideClassPtr ptr;
HRESULT hr = ptr.CreateInstance(__uuidof(SideBySideClass));
```

This error occurs:

> 0x8013101b : This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

Of course, I've tried to perform all the steps listed above, I try also to specify the runtime version in the manifest of the DLL, but it was not useful.

I also read [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsnotes/2012/08/10/error-0x8013101b-when-doing-a-registration-free-com-activation/). The problem is the same, but the solution, in my opinion, is not suitable for me, because I need to call a C# COM object from a native client.

Is there some workaround to apply, or do I need another approach to my problem?

Comment: Did  you manage to solve this problem?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I hope you have solved your problem. However yes I have solved my problem. In what I've written there is nothing wrong, except the runtime version  v2.0.50727 to v4.0.30319. I suggest to write your manifest on your own without using automatic tool ... using the sample i've listed before. I have also a little sample of a console application calling a c# library SxS if you need

Comment: Thanks for answering. I haven't suceeded with manifest stuff because native app did not want to load v4.0.30319 of CLR, it apparently loaded a lower version, with which component was incompatible. So, I've found another way to do it without registration and even without manifest, you just need to specify a path to you .net dll: 
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1199546/Interoping-NET-and-Cplusplus-through-registration
This approach works quite reliably for all cases I need.

Answer (score 3):

I appreciate this a little late, but for anyone else that comes across this...

I had this problem earlier today. My Registration Free COM library is built with .Net 4.5.2, my solution was to use the "runtimeVersion" attribute as follows

```
<clrClass 
   clsid="{...}" 
   progid="Library.Name" 
   threadingModel="Both" 
   name="Library.Name.Class"
   runtimeVersion="v4.0.30319">
```

Alternatively, you can leave out the runtimeVersion attribute (or specify v2.0.50272) and compile your library for .Net 3.5. Either solution appears to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am only guessing, but you say that the runtime version is 2.0.50727 in your manifest file, but you are having trouble compiling with 4? You have a mismatch in version with your manifest and your tools.

I just use the manifest tool to create and store the information in my assembly (in PostBuild step):

```
"$(PathToYourTools)\mt.exe" -managedassemblyname:$(TargetPath) -nodependency -outputresource:$(TargetPath);#2
```

It has the added benefit of not requiring to generate the typelib for the .NET assembly.

Comment: I've tried your hint adding in the Post Build Step the mt command to create and store the information, of course command is executed successfully  but the error 0x8013101b persist. I tried not only  to correct but also to remove al reference to the version